# Proof that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{3}]$ is a Euclidean Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

Let $R_d$ be the ring defined as $R_d=\left \{ x+y\omega : x,y\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$, where
$$\omega =
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{d}, & \text{if } \quad d \not \equiv 1\mod 4 \\
\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}, & \text{if } \quad d\equiv 1\mod 4.
\end{cases}$$

It has been proven that $R_d$ is Euclidean for several positive values of $d$.

> Does anyone know where I can find a proof that $R_d$ is Euclidean for $d=3$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

Define the norm on $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ to be $N(a + b \sqrt 3) = \vert a^2 - 3 b^2 \vert$.

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ with $\beta \neq 0$.

Say $\alpha = a + b \sqrt 3$ and $\beta = c + d \sqrt 3$.

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac\alpha\beta &= \frac{a + b \sqrt 3}{c + d \sqrt 3} \cdot \frac{c - d \sqrt 3}{c - d \sqrt 3} \\
&= \frac{ac - 3bd}{c^2 - 3d^2} + \frac{-ad  + bc}{c^2 - 3d^2} \sqrt 3 \\
&= r + s\sqrt 3
\end{align*}

where $r = \displaystyle  \frac{ac - 3bd}{c^2 - 3d^2}$ and $s = \displaystyle  \frac{-ad  + bc}{c^2 - 3d^2}$.

Let $p$ be the closest integer to $r$ and let $q$ be the closest integer to $s$. Notice that $\vert r - p \vert \leq 1/2$ and $\vert s - q \vert \leq 1/2$.

We want to show that $\alpha = (p + q\sqrt 3) \beta + \gamma$ for some $\gamma \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ such that either $\gamma = 0$ or $N(\gamma) < N(\beta)$. (We'll show the latter holds always.)

Define $\theta := (r - p) + (s - q)\sqrt 3$ and define $\gamma = \beta \cdot \theta \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ and observe that
\begin{align*}
\gamma &= \beta \cdot \theta\\
&= \beta ( (r - p) + (s - q)\sqrt 3)\\
&= \beta (r + s\sqrt 3) - \beta(p + q\sqrt 3) \\
&= \beta \cdot\frac\alpha\beta - \beta  (p + q\sqrt 3) \\
&= \alpha - \beta (p + q\sqrt 3) 
\end{align*}

Hence we have $\alpha = \beta(p + q\sqrt 3) + \gamma$.

Finally notice that
\begin{align*}
N(\gamma) &= N(\beta \cdot \theta) \\
&= N(\beta) \cdot N(\theta) \\
&= N(\beta) \cdot \vert (r - p)^2 - 3 (s - q)^2 \vert \\
&\leq N(\beta) \cdot \max\{ (r - p)^2, 3(s - q)^2\} \\
& \leq\frac34  N(\beta)\\
&< N(\beta)
\end{align*}

The key here was that $\vert (r - p)^2 - 3 (s - q)^2 \vert  \leq  \max\{ (r - p)^2, 3(s - q)^2\}$ since $(r - p)^2, 3(s - q)^2 \geq 0$ and then we use that $(r - p)^2 \leq 1/4$ and $3(s - q)^2 \leq 3/4$.

Comment: When you're proving that $N(\gamma) < N(\beta)$, you say that $N(\theta) = |(p-r)^2 - 3(q-s)^2|$. However, $N$ was only defined for elements in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. You showed that $(\beta)(\theta) \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. But how does this imply that $\theta \in \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$?

Comment: That's a very good question! We can just think of the norm $N$ on $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ as being the norm on $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 3]$, restricted to $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$.

Comment: why is |p - r |< 1/2 and |q- s| < 1/2

Comment: @user136266, because we *define* $p, q$ to be the closest integers to $r, s$, respectively. Say $p = \frac14$, the closest integer is $0$ and the difference is less than $\frac12$, if $p = \frac34$, then the closest integer is $1$. If $p = \frac12$, then pick either $0$ or $1$ and the claim holds (less than **or** equal to).

Comment: @RobertCardona how is 1/4 and 1/2 integers?  these are not integers. i think you meant r but even so why must r be only these 3 possibilities?If i have a, c = 1 and b,d = 0. Then r = 0 and so u can't find an integer p such that p-r < 1/2.

Comment: @user10024395 p=0